# Extend/Override jquery.ajax.done function to detect .net logon screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm using forms authentication on an asp.net MVC application and I'm using jquery and ajax to create a rich user interface. Some users tend to leave the page open for hours and their login session is expiring as expected. If the user click a link or reloads the page the login screen is returned as expected. If they click a button or trigger an ajax call the ajax call is returning the login html instead of the expected html or JASON result. Resulting in a mangled page with half a login screen.

As I've already coded a lot of ajax calls I thought I could extend or override the default .done event to add a check for the login screen before continuing with whatever event I've programmed.

For example i have this function :

```
function CallAjax() {
    $.ajax({type: "GET", url: "foo" })
     .done(function (data) { $('#result').val(data); });
}
```

is it possible to override the default implementation of .done so do a check without rewriting this function?  My check would probably to see if the result is a html response if so search for "login" to see if its the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried Darin's suggestion but after hours of trying I just couldn't get it to work in my set up.  However I stumbled across this rather simpler solution which worked for me first time:

just add this to the global.asax

```
protected void Application_EndRequest()
{
    var context = new HttpContextWrapper(this.Context);

    if (FormsAuthentication.IsEnabled && 
        context.Response.StatusCode == 302 &&
        context.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from http://jvance.com/blog/2012/09/21/FixFormsAuthentication302.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to extend the ASP.NET Forms Authentication module as Phil Haack explained in [`this blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx) so that it no longer redirects to the login page when requested with AJAX but returns a 401 HTTP status code instead. Then you could simply use the `.fail` callback and intercept the 401 status code. The `.done` handler will not be invoked in this case.